# Flex/AS Component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Hi i want to make a component to draw a Graph like this: [image]

However, the Area under the Graph should be filled with red color. I have 2 different types of values i use on x value i want to use time and on the y i want to use money value both ints but how should i start? My Idea on start was to draw Sprites with Vector but that dont work, because he starts on top left regular zero point and i cant fill the complete area under the graph.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;


    [SWF(backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" , width="500" , height="500")]
    public class Highprofil extends Sprite
    {
        public function Highprofil() 
        {
            var drawSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var localPoint:Point = drawSprite.localToGlobal(new Point(0,999));
        var money:Array = new Array(1,2,10,20,10,2,1);
        var time:Array = new Array(12,58,52,41,66,98,3);
        var geo:Shape=new Shape();
        var testdata:Vector.<Number>=new Vector.<Number>;
        for(var i:int=0;i<money.length;i++){
        testdata.push(money[i]);
        testdata.push(time[i]);
            }

        var commands:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
        for(var j:int=0;j<money.length;j++){
            commands.push(j);

        }



        drawSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF0000); // Color Red

        drawSprite.graphics.drawPath(commands, testdata); // Draw the path
        drawSprite.graphics.endFill();

        addChild(drawSprite);
        }
    }
}
```

This will be a Uicomponent dont know if its easier to realize in flex component, but actually it doesnt even look close like a graph.

Comment: Show the actual code you've tried.

Comment: Have you looked into Flex charting controls at all?

Comment: Yes I want to write a new UIcomponent and later customize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there misses some points clearly stated in the docs of [Graphics.drawPath()](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawPath%28%29) and has some indentation issues ;) .

The most important part is, that the `commands` Vector should contain values from [GraphicsPathCommand](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/GraphicsPathCommand.html#LINE_TO), in your case `2` for `LINE_TO` to draw lines between the coordinates.

Then to get the desired graph, you need to order the X values (and the Y values accordingly). I ordered those values manually in the code and made up  my own Y values for testing.

Then in your loop you first added the Y values and then the X values to `testdata`, but it needs to be the other way around `[x, y, x, y, x, y,...]`.

Only doing this gave me a great graph that pointed downwards. So I continued with tweaking the code a little bit (see comments)and came up with this:
http://wonderfl.net/c/6BrY
(there you can fork it and play with it seeing the result instantly)

for direct/later reference here is the code only:

```
package {
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.GraphicsPathCommand;

public class FlashTest extends Sprite {

    public function FlashTest() {
        var drawSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

        //the values for the X axis need to be sorted!
        var time:Array  = new Array( 3, 12, 41, 52, 58, 66, 98); 
        var money:Array = new Array( 4,  3,  9, 20, 10,  8, 15);

        var testdata:Vector.<Number>=new Vector.<Number>();
        var commands:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();

        var currentY:Number, maxY:Number = 0;
        //some "scaling" for the values, otherwise those are pixels
        const scaleX:int = 3, scaleY:int = 10;

        for(var i:int=0;i<money.length;i++){
            //first X values!
            testdata.push(time[i]*scaleX);

            //then Y values
            currentY = money[i]*scaleY;
            testdata.push(-currentY);//adding negative values so the graph goes upwards
            if(currentY > maxY){
                maxY = currentY;//keep track of highest point in graph
            }

            commands.push(GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO);
        }

        //get the graph back to zero maxX/0 so it gets filled correctly (independent of last X value)
        testdata.push(time[time.length-1]*scaleX, 0);
        commands.push(GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO);

        drawSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF0000); 
        drawSprite.graphics.drawPath(commands, testdata);
        drawSprite.graphics.endFill();

        addChild(drawSprite);
        drawSprite.y = maxY + 10;//moving the sprite down so the graph is completely visible (+10 pixel padding)
        drawSprite.x = 10;//(+10 pixel padding)

    }
}
}
```

Comment: ah ok ty but have still 1 Problem about scaling. As a Component i want the graph to fill all time the full width i choosen for the component and high also but dont realy understand how to implement this, because when i use scaleX to scale it in size it doesnt fit anymore if i only add 1 big value in x or y. I added a picture for better understanding http://imgur.com/SYyMIZB  thanks for all help

Comment: in this case you would need to collect min/max values first without scaling and decide for the scaling depending on the relation between available space and those values. Of course this has to be recalculated each tie values or the available size changes. Does this answer your additional question?

Comment: as you also tagged your question with flex: if you want to integrate this with the Flex Framework, you should get familiar with the Flex lifecycle (depending on the flex version you are using) to communicate the proper size of your component to it (look for how to implement `commitProperties`, `measure` and `updateDisplaylist`)

Comment: isnt flex and as3 similar the same? thought because i can easily add as3 code to flex it isnt that huge jump from as3  component to a flex compnent

Comment: While Flex is a library(+ some tools) based on the language Actionscript3  you can of course add AS3 code. But Flex provides a lifecycle for its components (e.g. in Flex3 everything that extends UIComponent) to stay performant with the limited resources of the Runtime (like FlashPlayer in the Browser). So if your application is doing more then "drawing some things on the screen", like complex UI layouts and you want it to feel performant for the user, you need to know at least basics about the [Flex Lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6357906/684134).